# Keycloak Failing to Start. Trying to update database, but don't have a DB lock acquired

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to start keycloak using :

```
<Keycloak_DIrectory> ./bin/standalone.sh
```

I am trying to connect to Postgresql for User Management in SQL:

But Keycloak is failing to start and giving following exception:

```
12:16:32,322 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2209)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:299)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:240)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to update database, but don't have a DB lock acquired
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:60)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:48)
        at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:103)
        at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
        at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
        at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:103)
        at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:161)
        at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:154)
        at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:41)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:184)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:141)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:106)
        at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:287)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
        ... 19 more
```

Any clue why it is giving Caused by: **java.lang.IllegalStateException**: Trying to update database, but don't have a DB lock acquired

Comment: Is there something else connected to the database preventing Keycloak from obtaining the lock? Does the database user have full permissions to be able to setup the table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to 2.1.0 or later.

This problem seems to be caused by [KEYCLOAK-3149](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3149) and fixed by [KEYCLOAK-3344](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3344).

See also:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/981ff90c81a3cc8ad774ea77be678d88c9d43281#diff-22ef19a720ece2d895a0b70ec0d8e5e5